# Link Saleforce to Visual Studio and GIT

Tags: github, installation, salesforce, vscode-extensions

I am trying to connect Salesforce to VSCode and GIT.

I have downloaded VS, and CLI and have GIT Hub however I am having trouble connecting Salesforce to VS so that I can create a repository.

I have also got the recommended extensions.
I am new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Thank You,

Lorr

I have created a project but unable to locate SF.
I have tried to authorize org but it cant find this.
I have managed to link what looks like SF but it is not correct please see attached.
[VS as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5pYK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that VSCode is just a text editor fundamentally. All of the additional features need us to install the related VSCode extension.

You need three things:

**1, Salesforce CLI command tool**

[Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/salesforcecli)

After install, you need to configure the path of the command tool to the machine system environment variable(The default path of the tool is `C:\Program Files\sf\bin`.):

[image]

**2, 'Salesforce Extension Pack' extension of VSCode**

All of the available operations(including connect) to Salesforce is based on this extension, you can search and install it in this place:

[image]

After waiting for about 5 minutes, the available operations will be loaded, you can auth to login after press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and then search 'sfdx':

[image]

After this, you will be able to connect to Salesforce from the VSCode side.

**3, 'GitHub' extension of VSCode**

[image]

Still press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to show all of the available operations and search 'github':

[image]

After selecting 'Publish to GitHub', you will be transfer to the login page, and after accept step, you will be able to connect and push the local content to GitHub.